# Should JWT's be validated on every request?

Tags: cookies, jwt, aws, cognito

I have been unable to find a definitive answer to the above question.

We currently use JWTs from [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) for our Authentication. Currently the JWTs that are returned are too large to use in Cookies (over the 4KB limit) so we do not store the entire JWT in cookie.

Our current process is to login the user, then validate the ID token (JWT) that is received. Then create a `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and `Cookie` from this information. The Cookie includes the relevant ID information of the user and the ExpirationDate of the original received ID Token.

This means for all future page loads, we simply check if the Cookie is expired or not. If it is, we know they need to login again.

**Would the above work correctly, or does the JWT need to be sent as the cookie and validated on every page request?**

Comment: Usually the answer is "yes" but it depends on what is in the JWT and what a page does. Without that information this question can't really be answered. Also, why is your JWT so large? I suspect there is a completely different solution hiding somewhere...

Comment: Just checking: what, exactly, is in your cookie? Putting the expiry in there is dangerous if there's no integrity protection (like a MAC or signature) to prevent an attacker who gains access to an expired cookie from un-expiring it, but depending on what you mean by "the relevant ID information" that could be the least of your problems.

Comment: @conor Mancone - Cognito just seems to serve up huge JWTs. There is an option to use Lambda and suppress claim info that is not required. I’ve seen other posts online of people complaining about the size

Comment: @CBHacking - the cookie is typically the jwt token itself. With FormsAuthentication you can set the expiring date of the cookie. I thought that expired date could not be changed or amended after being set.

Comment: @ConorMancone tagging for notification

Comment: @CBHacking tagging for notification

Comment: There's no need to tag people multiple times (or at all, really; usually we get the notification anyhow). You didn't actually answer what, exactly, you're proposing to put in the cookie, so I wrote an answer explaining the situation. Be aware, by the way, that cookie validity periods are absolutely not set in stone, and also just *don't matter* security-wise; all that matters is the validity period of the data ***in*** the cookie.

Comment: Just the ID information? So if I put a cookie on my computer that says ID=admin;expires=12/31/2999 you'll just accept that I'm admin??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To directly answer your question: it's necessary to verify the authenticity of a session token every time you receive a new connection. That doesn't necessarily mean every time you receive a request; if your system is never going to combine multiple users' requests into a single connection (which is very rare on client-to-server but relatively common on, say, load-balancer-to-server) then you can verify a connection's token only once and allow multiple requests over it during the lifetime of the session (though this is still riskier than verifying every request, because somebody might manage to cause the client to send a fraudulent request without knowing the token). Even when the risks are acceptable, if the session ends (user logs out, times out, etc.) before the connection breaks, you obviously need to stop trusting the connection.

---

As I implied in my comment, for a system like yours it really, REALLY depends on what you're storing in the cookie. For example, if you're storing the expiration data in the cookie value without cryptographic integrity, or worse-yet just relying on the expiration feature of browser cookies in general, that's risky because there *isn't* anything preventing somebody from modifying that expiry. Cookie expiry means almost nothing security-wise, just that the browser will delete the cookie at that point. Anybody who knows the name and value of that cookie can still use it, though. (Perhaps they pulled it out of a log months after the cookie expired; they can still set a cookie with that name and value.) You need to either track which cookies are valid server-side, or you need to include the expiry *in the cookie* and prevent it from being modified via some form of *cryptographic integrity check*, such as a digital signature or Message Authentication Code (MAC).

This is, incidentally, how JWTs work. A JWT has three parts. Two of them are data: the header (saying who issued the JWT and how long it's good for and so on) and the claims (saying who the bearer of that JWT is and what privileges they have, according to the issuer). The third part is the *signature* (which is often an HMAC, because they're usually shorter and cheaper to verify than public key signatures, although in some cases such signatures are more secure) which is based on a cryptographic hash of the other parts and prevents the data parts from being forged or modified without a cryptographic key that is kept secret. When you "verify" a JWT, you're performing a cryptographic operation to ensure that the JWT's signature is correct for the other parts, meaning it hasn't been tampered with.

You say "the cookie is typically the JWT itself", and that's true, but in this case "typically" obviously doesn't apply. If you're storing only part of the JWT - for example, everything except the signature - that's completely insecure; I can just forge a JWT for another user and send it to your server, and the server will think I'm that user who has authenticated and then been handed this truncated JWT as a cookie. Same deal if you're doing things like stripping off the JWT header for the cookie; the signature part is no longer valid, so you can't tell the difference between a legitimate cookie and one I made up (or edited to claim I'm some other user).

---

It sounds like what you're proposing doing is using the JWT from Cognito to authenticate / authorize the user, and then creating your own session token for subsequent use. This is basically how many single-sign-on (SSO) systems work; there's nothing wrong with the idea in general. However, it relies on you having a secure session token infrastructure.

There are, broadly speaking, two ways to do session tokens safely:

1. You issue a short-ish token (usually just a cryptographically random string) to every authenticated user, and also store the table of valid tokens (and what users they map to) server-side.

   - Advantage: the server always knows which tokens are valid; it can store expiry information where the user can't even see (much less edit) it and it can prematurely expire tokens (if the user logs out or requests to end other sessions).
   - Advantage: no long-term secret that an attacker could steal to be able to forge valid tokens.
   - Advantage: the only cryptographic operation is the random number generator that creates the tokens.
   - Disadvantage: if you run a cluster of servers, they all need to be able to check, constantly, whether the token is valid. This requires either a distributed memory cache, some tricky behavior where you bypass load-balancing to lock a user to one server, or a whole lot of database queries.
   - Verdict: simple, but doesn't scale well.
2. You create a token that contains the session details (user identity, authorization, session expiry, etc.) and use a secret cryptographic key to sign the token and prevent the user from modifying or forging it. This is how JWTs work.

   - Advantage: no server-side state at all. So long as every server knows the key needed to verify the tokens, the server doesn't need to remember anything about which sessions are active.
   - Advantage: a token can be issued by one server and used by another. They don't even need to be owned by the same entity, so long as the validating server trusts the issuing server. Asymmetric (public key) cryptography allows the issuing server to keep secret the "private key" required to create valid tokens, while any server with the corresponding "public key" can verify them.
   - Disadvantage: it's hard to expire a token early. There are ways to do it but they're messy and don't scale well either. Therefore, the tokens are usually short-lived, and are re-issued periodically (often via a "refresh token" of the first type, which is used rarely enough to not be a scalability problem).
   - Disadvantage: the signing key is the linchpin of the whole system. If an attacker obtains it, then the attacker can forge valid tokens and the server won't know the difference. Periodic rotation of the signing key can help, but even a very short compromise (the period between the signing key becoming known to the attacker, and it ceasing to be a trusted signing key) can be devastating.
   - Disadvantage: cryptography is hard to get right. Although this is a pretty simple cryptosystem, it's still got enough moving parts that there's a risk of somebody screwing it up. Also, there's a risk if, say, the cryptographic hash used to create the signature is broken, and somebody can create a different token body which produces the same hash. The work-around here is just to use a well-trusted implementation written and reviewed by people who know what they're doing, keep it up to date, and use modern cryptographic primitives (for example, the SHA2 or SHA3 family, rather than SHA or MD5).
   - Verdict: usable with every kind and scale of system, but harder to get right and more likely to fail catastrophically.

Looking just at the list of advantages and disadvantages, you might think the first approach is better, but it turns out that the scaling thing is a huge issue for many systems. The hybrid approach (short-lived type-2 access tokens plus session-lifetime type-1 refresh tokens that can be used to get a new access token) works well, at the cost of some additional complexity, but still doesn't remove the need for the signing key to be kept absolutely secret and the access tokens to be verified securely.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @CBHacking. To give some background we have an asp.net application running on a pool of web servers. My initial plan was to receive the access token and validate it against the provider. Then store the entire JWT content in a secure/HTTPonly cookie. On pages that needs authorization we would validate the cookie content (the JWT) again and confirm it has not expired and provide access to the resource should it validate and be within time. Would this approach work or should we be storing the JWTs in SQL and having a cookie that helps access that data?

Comment: Storing the entire JWT in a cookie and validating it whenever the user makes a request requiring authorization (which is normally every request after logging in) is fine, security-wise. However, you said that the JWT was too large for a cookie, so I was attempting to give you alternatives to the "store entire JWT in a cookie" approach.

Comment: That’s great to know. Thanks for the other info. I think it’s an issue with the claims info from Cognito being so large I’ll use a lambda for reduce the claims to bring the size down. Would it also be plausible just to keep the info in session state server side? Then the cookie shouldn’t be required at all? We could just get the session data on each request check the expiry date and serve info if valid?

Comment: That works, assuming that you are setting another way for the client to identify itself to the server (probably a session cookie). However, it does have the scalability problem; you'll need to make sure that the client is connecting to the server that already knows about it, or else that all servers in your pool have knowledge of all clients.

Comment: This is a great answer! One more way to manage session securely is to combine the good parts of both the methods described above: use short lived JWT access tokens, and long lived opaque refresh tokens. Use the refresh token to geta new access AND a new refresh token (called rotating refresh tokens). This will allow you to mitigate / minimise most of the disadvantages mentioned above, while getting all the upside. Fore more information on this, please see [my blog post](https://supertokens.io/blog/the-best-way-to-securely-manage-user-sessions?s=s).